# 准备过奖黑板政治生物历史脑 in English please?

Tags: translation, meaning

My friend wrote this on his timeline, and I need to know... Please help me....

准备过奖黑板政治生物历史脑.  What does this mean??? Btw, he is not an advanced Chinese speaker,so some grammars might be incorrect.. But I just need to know what he's trying to say

I mean, I tried to use the google translator, but it gave me some impossible answer

Comment: He probably googled the translation into Chinese as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not even a sentence. That is just a bunch of words put together and they don't make any sense as a sentence. It literally means "prepare award blackboard politics biology history brain". Also, don't trust Google Translate when translating sentences. I often use Google Translate to translate sentences just for giggles. :)

Comment: 过奖：小马词典：to over-praise; to flatter，bkrs：overpraise; give  too much credit 过分的赞扬
您过奖了，(谦) overpraise; undeserved compliment:
您过奖了。 You flatter me.
生物：小马词典：organism; living creature; life form; biological;

Answer (score 0):

It is jibberish. Google was right. IMHO. I'm not advanced though.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Then could you guys uhh... Track back and try to guess what he really meant to say? Because the google translation of this is stupid...

Comment: You should revise this into your question, as it is not an answer, but additional info.